# Can i compare two array using computed property in Vue js?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, computed-properties

I am so sorry if I didn't explain this clearly. I want to create an edit amenity like Airbnb. 
I have the "Amenity" array with id, name. Then I loaded all the amenities for house_id = 2 to an array called "house_amenities". 
What I want is when a record in house_amenities with amenites_id match with id from "Amenities" a checkbox will be ticked. 
What i want to achieved: [1]:https://postimg.cc/bGhvGGSP

I tried using the computed property but haven't had any luck yet. It always returned "[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

```html
<table class= "table table-striped" style="overflow-y: scroll">
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Amenities</th>
        <th>
            <span class="checkbox-custom checkbox-primary" style="padding:0px;margin:0px">
            <input class="selectable-item" type="checkbox">
            <label></label>
            </span>
        </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody v-for = "(amenity,index) in amenitiesLst">
        <tr v-for="(items,index) in houseAmenitiesLst>
            <td>{{index+1}}</td>
            <td>{{amenity.name}}</td>
            <td>
                <input class="selectable-item" type="checkbox" value="check[index]"  >
            </td>


        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And here is vue code:

```js
computed: {
    checked: function(){
        this.amenitiesLst.map(function(item){
            for(var i = 0; i < this.houseAmenitiesLst.length; i++)
            {
                if(item.id == this.houseAmenitiesLst[i].amenities_id)
                    return true;
                else 
                    return false;    
            }
        })
    }
},
```

Comment: `return` in for means it gets only first time executed.

Comment: Can you tell me more about this? It's mean only the first record in this.houseAmenitiesLst got compared? I get the error "[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

Comment: yes, only the first one. Becaue if it's either true or false, it ends cycle.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that the `computed` property is executed before you have any values in your `amenitiesList` in your function just add a check to only execute when is initiated like this:

```
checked: function(){
if(this.amenitiesLst){
        this.amenitiesLst.map(function(item){
            for(var i = 0; i < this.houseAmenitiesLst.length; i++)
            {
                if(item.id == this.houseAmenitiesLst[i].amenities_id)
                    return true;
                else 
                    return false;    
            }
        })
    }
return
    }
```

The computed property is executed each time a dependency changes therefore as soon as `amentiesList` is initialized it will return your value. You may also need to put a v-if on your template to make sure you don't have a render error.

Comment: i tried your suggestion but it still return the same error :(

Comment: try `if(!!this.amentiesList)` also try: `if(this.amenitiesList && this.amentiesList.length > 0`

Comment: now it throw this error: "[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined". I checked and it seems that this "checked[index]" is causing the error. I've made a jsfiddle. Can you take a look for me? http://jsfiddle.net/alexvu2412/5dg64vcj/9/

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the context, `this` inside the `map` function doesn't refer to the Vue instance so `houseAmenitiesLst` is not defined

Try with:

```
computed: {
    checked: function(){
        this.amenitiesLst.map((item) => {
            for(var i = 0; i < this.houseAmenitiesLst.length; i++)
            {
                if(item.id == this.houseAmenitiesLst[i].amenities_id)
                    return true;
                else 
                    return false;    
            }
        })
    }
},
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion I tried but it's still throwing this error "[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined". I think this checked[index] is the one causing this. Still trying to understand why :(

Comment: Yeah i tried it too on the jsfiddle. My question is: why do you have a v-for on the tbody? I probably didn't understand what you want to achieve. Do you just need a list with all amenities and check the ones who are mapped into houseAmenities?

Comment: i want to achieve something like Airbnb did on their edit page. They have all amenities shown then checked the one that house already have and unchecked if it doesn't. Like this picture: https://postimg.cc/bGhvGGSP

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/msr0wL7v/1/ i tweaked a bit your jsfiddle, is that what you want?

Comment: oh my, it is. Thank you so much.